# whats the average consecutive games this player shot 42% or better in a basketball game?

Tags: statistics

this would be easier to answer if you know sports.... so im trying to figure out an average for something. i want to know how much consecutive games a basketball player has shot over 42% in a game. So i did some but i need help solving. I went to the players game log (which shows you every single game in order and the shooting % for each game)and got the amount of games played (which was 77) and the amount of games he shot over 42%. My question is how do i solve it? Im trying to find out the average amount of consecutive games this player shot over 42%. Do i divide 40 by 77? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This depends highly on the structure on the order of the data. For example if I played 10 games and took one shot in each game then my scores might look like this:
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

or like this
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
First case is average consecutive shots over 42% = 1
Second case it is 5 because there was only one instance of consecutive shots.

You just have to count the strings of percents over 42% and then take (total number of percents over 42%/number of strings of over 42%)

Comment: joe, thank you so much. i really appriciate it. to be sure. i am talking about the average amount of GAMES where  a player shot at least 42%, not average amount of shots, correct?

Comment: right I think we are talking about the same thing

Comment: okay thank you. do u mind if i show u the data. its long but it would be easier for me

Comment: "X" would be a game where he DID shoot 42% or better. 
"O" would be a game where he did NOT shoot 42% or better

OOOO XX O X OOOO X OOO XX O XX O XX O XXX OO XX OOO X OO XX O XXXX O X O X O XXXXX OO XXX OO XXX OO XX OO XX OO X O

What would the average consecutive games shooting 42% or better be above?

Comment: take total number of X and divide it by the number of "strings" of X's

Comment: ok great! thanks joe!